# Finding a lower bound on the roots

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers

Question Statement-

If $z$ is a complex number and $x_0, x_1,..., x_{2n}$ are real then prove that all the roots of the equation of $$(sinx_0)z^{2n}+(cosx_1)z^{2n-1}+(sinx_2)z^{2n-2}+...+(cosx_{2n-1})z+sinx_{2n}=b$$
lie in the region $$|z|>1-\frac{1}{|b|}$$
My working-
I tried using the conventional methods of vieta's relations and taking conjugates and somehow arrive on some conclusions. Then I tried proving that maybe all the roots have to be real or all the root's complex conjugate must also be a root, as only possible complex coefficient is $b$. I have notice that the inequality essentially means we have to prove $|z|>1$ and also all the sin and cos functions essentially imply that all coefficients are less than or equal to 1 in magnitude. But I haven't gotten much out of it. Would love some hints!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: assume for the same of contradiction that $z$ is a root of the polynomial equation and $|z| \le 1-1/|b|$. Find an upper bound for the left-hand side using the triangle inequality and the sum of a geometric series.

Comment: Thanks! I tried using proof by contradiction by same claim but couldn't see how, thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 1):

The $\cos$ and $\sin$ here are not relevant, we can simplify to:
$$
\sum_{n=0}^N a_n \ z^n = b, \ \mbox{with all} \ |a_n| \leq 1 
$$
Then use that for $|z|\geq 1$ the claim it is trivially true and that for $|z|<1$ we can write:
$$
|b| = \left|\sum_{i=0}^{2n} a_i \ z^i\right| \leq 
\left|\sum_{i=0}^{2n} |a_i| \cdot |z|^i\right| \leq 
\left|\sum_{i=0}^{2n} 1 \cdot |z|^i\right| <
\left|\sum_{i=0}^\infty |z|^i\right| \leq 
\frac{1}{1-|z|},
$$
which gives the required result since there is one $<$ sign in the sequence.

Comment: This is basically what Greg hinted me to do, anyways thanks for the answer

Comment: Yes Greg's answer showed up too late on my side...

Comment: yeah I think we were composing our answers simultaneously :)